# JQuery/Javascript select not visible element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a page with tabs, i would like select every span/input on each tabs, but not those in a hidden div.

There is a difference betwwen the hidden from tabs, and the hidden attribute ?.
For undertand this question, there is my code :

**HTML**

```
  <input type="button" value="click me" id="btn">
  <main>
  <input id="tab1" class="tab" type="radio" name="tabs" checked>
  <label for="tab1">Codepen</label>

  <input id="tab2" class="tab" type="radio" name="tabs">
  <label for="tab2">Dribbble</label>

  <input id="tab3" class="tab" type="radio" name="tabs">
  <label for="tab3">Dropbox</label>


<section id="content1">
<span id="span1">span1</span>
<input id="inp1" type="text" value="val" />
</section>

<section id="content2">
<span id="span2">span2</span>
<input id="inp2" type="text" value="val2" />  
  <div hidden>
    <span id="span3">span3</span>
    <input id="inp3" type="text" value="val3" />
  </div>
</section>

<section id="content3">
<span id="span4">span4</span>
<input id="inp4" type="text" value="val4" />  
  <div>
    <span id="span5">span5</span>
    <input id="inp5" type="text" value="val5" />
  </div>

   <div hidden>
      <div>
        <span id="span6">span6</span>
        <input id="inp6" type="text" value="val6" />
        </div>
  </div>
</section>
</main>
```

And my try in **Jquery**

```
$("#btn").click(function() {

$.each($("section").find("span, input"), function() {
    if ($(this).is(":visible")) {
        console.log($(this).attr("id"));
   }

})
})
```

The output is :

```
span1
inp1
```

If i remove the if condition, output is :

```
span1
inp1
span2
inp2
span3
inp3
span4
inp4
span5
inp5
span6
inp6
```

And what i expect is :

```
span1
inp1
span2
inp2
span4
inp4
inp5
span5
```

And there is my [JSFiddle for live demo](https://jsfiddle.net/2oq8a7n6/1/)

I don't know if this is clear, ask me in comment for more explication, and sorry for my english. Thanks

Comment: problem is with the css, there is `section { display:none }` which makes everything hidden, except one section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two solutions for this

```
$("#btn").click(function() {

console.log("Method 1");

$.each($("section").find("span, input"), function() {
  if ($(this).closest("[hidden]").length == 0)
   {
     console.log($(this).attr("id"));
   }

})

console.log("Method 2");

$.each($("section > span, section > input, section > div:not([hidden]) span, section > div:not([hidden]) input"), function() {
  if ($(this).closest("[hidden]").length == 0)
   {
     console.log($(this).attr("id"));
   }

})
})
```

Answer (score 0):

hiding the element is not with hidden attribute but with CSS like this: `<div style="display:none">` or `<div style="visibility:hidden">`